# After creating a custom model for custom roles now if create a user and give him 'admin' authentication i cant login to admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,User
from django.utils.html import escape,mark_safe
# Create your models here.
class user(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def login_view(request):
form = AuthenticationForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username,password=password)
    if user.is_admin==True:
        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponse(f"Welcome {username}")
    else:
        return HttpResponse('failled')

return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

now if i create a user and give him any of these privilege and then call the user anywhere
it shows
**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_admin'**

Comment: Can you give an example where are you using the user and getting that error?

Comment: `if user.is_admin==True:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse(f"Welcome {username}")`

Comment: Please add the full view code to the question not as a comment

Comment: added in question

Comment: Can you add the rest of the view, where does the `user` variable come from?

Comment: i added full view . I created a **login view**

Comment: actually its working with the superuser i created using terminal but now after created a user that user cant log in

Comment: The call to `authenticate` is returning `None`, authentication is failing. How exactly are you creating this user, can you show the code/command used? Have you configured `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to point to your model?

Comment: i added this in settings.py **AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.user'**

Comment: and i am creating the user through localhost admin panel

Comment: Have you configured the admin to use your custom model and not the built-in model? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin

Comment: no i didnt do that actually i am new to django

Comment: can you suggest me what should be changed in my code

Comment: There is a full example in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example. Have a look at the `admin.py` example

Comment: i am not understanding what change should be made according to the documentation

Comment: i used `admin.site.register (user)` in my admin.py before